# How do I SQL query from Azure Web Role to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express hosted on VM Role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, sql-server-2008r2-express, azure-vm-role

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on Azure VM Role (1 extra small instance).

Because of hosting very old banking system, which is not able to connect to SQL Azure. Data persistency is reached via Azure Storage Page Blob. I have written a Windows Service, which can mount VHD file and also can attach MDF database file to SQL Server.

My problem is that I need to SQL query from Azure Web Role to SQL Server hosted on Azure VM Role.
I tried nearly everything:

I have opened TCP 1433, UDP 1434, added SQL Browser to Windows Firewall.
I have enabled remote connection, SQL Server Browser, TCP/IP, Named Pipes on SQL Server.
I have changed TCP/IP port to 1433 and I have disabled dynamic port.

I have already read:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/b5f2967e-57e6-4099-9077-fb6d74897dbf

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuremanagement/thread/2b64a56f-fda7-4247-b016-9d25bbeebe8b

[How to access sql server installed on Azure VM (VM Role ) outside of VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502729/how-to-access-sql-server-installed-on-azure-vm-vm-role-outside-of-vm)

If you were so kind and wanted to help me, I would send you all the screenshot from my settings.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,

Martin David

Comment: So if you're read that last question you know that there are issues using the default sql server ports, have you tried setting it up using different ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wenchao Zeng from Microsoft Contingent Staff gave me a solution:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/c7124598-4894-4b6c-8987-709a9f788ea4